# Javascript: Callback in constructor

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I'm trying to write OO javascript for an object that has an expensive initialization process that will callback a function when its done.

The problem is that the caller needs to use the functions of that same object in the callback routine, and the object doesn't exist yet:

```
// ctor for foo object
function foo(callback) {

    // do slow initialization here..

    // callback when done
    callback();
};

foo.prototype = function() {

    return {
        // doStuff method
        doStuff: function() {
          alert('stuff done');
        }
    };        
}();

// instantiate the foo object, passing in the callback
var f = new foo(function() {

    //Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'doStuff' of undefined 
    f.doStuff();

});​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmEbb/1/)
What am I missing here?

Comment: I fail to see why you need a callback to a function that completes synchronously where the callback does not return a useful value.

Comment: The 'slow initialization' actually involves a 3rd party library which expects to be passed the callback function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be a simple fix.  First, make sure your callback is called with the `this` object set to the current object

```
function foo(callback) {
    // do slow initialization here..

    callback.call(this);
};
```

Then adjust how you make your callback

```
var f = new foo(function() {
    this.doStuff();
});​
```

Here's your [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmEbb/3/)

Comment: The issue is resolved by not referencing an object, but, instead, the "this" keyword which resolves the current context.

Comment: Though the OP's approach sounds really weird, this is probably the best approach, the OP was just forgetting to allow access to the instance from the callback. I would prefer to pass  `this` as a parameter to the callback, doesn't really matter though, just a preference

Answer (score 2):

Here's why it doesn't work: when JavaScript is executing the code, before it can set `f`, it needs to evaluate the `new foo(...)` expression. Inside of the constructor, it calls the callback. JavaScript still has not set `f` since the expression has not yet finished. As soon as the constructor finishes, `f` is set correctly, but it never gets there because you try to use `f` inside of the callback when it is still `undefined`.

---

You could call the callback on the next iteration through the event loop, so rather than:

```
callback();
```

You'd do:

```
setTimeout(callback, 0);
```

This would only work if you're already assuming that it completes asynchronously, though.

Comment: This worked for me in Node.  The accepted answer did not work in Node.

Comment: @haxor: If you're using Node, you might want to consider using `process.nextTick(callback)`.

Comment: process.nextTick(callback) did not call the callback.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is the intrinsic issue. Define doStuff within the constructor. The call as such:

```
var f = new Foo();
f.doStuff();
```

You can also create an init method to run whenever a new object is created. But, you should do this within the scope of the constructor... do not pass a callback to a constructor.

Comment: Adam Rackis has provided a very good alternate, however. But, I still do not recommend instantiating an object by passing a callback... unless you want to pass a different function each time. Either way, could be hard to maintain that code (in a larger application).

Comment: I would tend to agree.  Passing in a callback instructing an object to call its own method seems fishy to me...

Comment: Well it just wraps logic into objects that perhaps fit better in a mental model of 'things' vs 'doing stuff'. seems a little convoluted though.