Method inside a class in not getting invoked
So I have defined my class like the following. My constructor is getting called which in turn calls resolve as well. But when resolve is called, it doesn't in turn calls then method.
Could this be because of this? I tried declaring this.self = this as well in the constructor. But that didn't work. Appreciate any help.


class MyPromise{
  
    constructor(cb){
    cb(this.resolve, this.reject)//This works
  }
  
  resolve(value){
    this.then(value) //This is not called
  }
  
  then(val){
    console.log("here")
    return val;
  }
  

  reject(){
  }
  
}

var p = new MyPromise((resolve, reject)=>{
    resolve(42)
});




You'll need to bind the methods with the instance's this in the constructor. Like this.resolve = this.resolve.bind(this); for example.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999951/javascript-callback-in-constructor

this.resolve is actually working already. this.then is not

@ABGR cool. Try the suggestion just with this.then? Although you probably still need both

You need to bind resolve so that the this inside it still refers to your object. See the duplicate above.

@deceze So without that this prints undefined inside then() why's that btw?

In a nutshell: In a.b(), the this in b refers to a. this refers to whatever is before the . at call time. In your cb, you're only calling the function as f(). No ., no this. Whatever it'll refer to instead depends and is irrelevant, as it simply will not refer to your desired object.
